# Setting stroke and shadow on path cause Dramatic drop in average operations

Tags: performance, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I've been running a few test cases on path's stroke and shadow setting using KineticJS 4.7.
They can be found here : http://jsperf.com/pathshadow
It shows that setting stroke and shadow on path cause a drop of nearly 100% in number of operation. I run test with Chrome 32.0.1700.
Any ideas to improve those results ?
Thanks

Comment: Same results with kineticJS 5.0.1

Comment: Don't use shadows then? It is an expensive feature.

Answer (score 0):

As @Philipp says, shadows are an expensive operation.

If you need to move or copy your expensive shadowed path, you might consider converting it into an image object.

```
var pathImage=myPath.toImage();

var myPathImage=new Kinetic.Image({image:pathImage, ...});
```

That way subsequent moves/copies are not expensive because the shadow is saved in the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I didn't know that was possible. I've choosed to make a PNG of all the shadows and it's pretty cool now.